# systemverilog constraint dist using weights array

Tags: constraints, distribution, system-verilog

I need to be able to set a constraint dist with 64 different, changeble weights:

I need to random pick an index of range 0~63, when every index has its own weight / probability to be chosen.

I can write something like:

> constraint pick_chan_constraint {pick_channel dist{
>   0:=channel_weight[0], 1:=channel_weight[1], 2:=channel_weight[2],
>   3:=channel_weight[3], 4:=channel_weight[4], 5:=channel_weight[5],
>   6:=channel_weight[6], 7:=channel_weight[7], 8:=channel_weight[8],
>   9:=channel_weight[9], 10:=channel_weight[10], 11:=channel_weight[11],
>   12:=channel_weight[12], 13:=channel_weight[13],
>   14:=channel_weight[14],  … ...
>
> NUM_OF_CHANS-1 := channel_weight[NUM_OF_CHANS-1] }}

Obviously it's bad writing and a bad idea, out of 2 reasons:

No flexibility- if NUM_OF_CHANS changes, I'll need to change the code.

It's long and ugly and almost unreadable.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 18.5.4 Distribution shows the dist_list needs to be a list of `dist_item`s and a `dist_item` is defined as a `value_range [ dist_weight ]`. In other words the distribution needs to be listed out.

Instead of using a `constraint` you could create a queue array (§ 7.10 Queues) and then use the shuffle method (§ 7.12.2 Array ordering methods). Example:

```
int channel_weight [64];
int pick_channel;
int weight_chain [$];

weight_chain.delete(); // make sure it is empty
foreach (channel_weight[i]) begin
  repeat (channel_weight[i]) begin
    weight_chain.push_back(i);
  end
end
weight_chain.shuffle(); // randomize order
assert( weight_chain.size() > 0) else $error("all channel_weights are 0");
pick_channel = weight_chain[0];
```